# Let $S = \{[1, 2, -3]^T, [-2, 1, 1]^T\}$. Is $[-5, 2, 3]^T \in span(S)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$a – 2b = -5$

$2a + b = 2$

$-3a + b = 3$

Then

$3a – b = - 3$

$-3a + b = 3$

implies

$0 = 0$

But what does that mean? That there are no $a, b$ such that no linear combination in $S$ equals $[-5, 2, 3]^T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0=0$ doesn't tell you anything, its just a true statement. Backing up a step, the fact that you can get the third equation from the first two tells you that the third one is redundant and you only need to solve the first two.

Comment: Then $a = \frac {-1}{5}$ and $b = \frac {12}{5}$  is all we need, correct?

Comment: yea, you can check it directly.

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly identified, this question is equivalent to asking if the system
\begin{array}{rcrcr}
x & - & 2\,y & = & -5 \\
2\,x & + & y & = & 2 \\
-3\,x & + & y & = & 3
\end{array}
has a solution. To do this, note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}
\rref
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & -5 \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
-3 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1/5 \\
0& 1 & 12/5 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This tells us that 
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{5}\right)\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\-3\end{bmatrix}+
\left(\frac{12}{5}\right)\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}-5\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}
$$
That is, the answer is yes!

Comment: @ Brian Fitzpatrick, thank you.